# Login and logout with python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, facebook, python-social-auth

I used `python-social-auth` to implement login with Facebook and Twitter.

**Settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'social.apps.django_app.default',
...)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
   'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
   'django.core.context_processors.debug',
   'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
   'django.core.context_processors.media',
   'django.core.context_processors.static',
   'django.core.context_processors.tz',
   'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
   'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
   'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
   'social.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
   'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_KEY = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_SECRET = ''

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    # recibe vía backend y uid las instancias de social_user y user
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    # Recibe según user.email la instancia del usuario y lo reemplaza con uno que recibió anteriormente
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    # Trata de crear un username válido según los datos que recibe
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    # Crea un usuario nuevo si uno todavía no existe
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    # Trata de conectar las cuentas
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    # Recibe y actualiza social_user.extra_data
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    # Actualiza los campos de la instancia user con la información que obtiene vía backend
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
)

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('Vulpini.co')
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('Vulpini.co')
LOGOUT_URL = reverse_lazy('logout')
```

Well, this is the configuration in settings.py

and this is my
**URLs.py**

```
url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',{'template_name':'app/index.html'}, name='Vulpini.co'),
    url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', name='logout'),
```

and this is my

**loginpartial.html**

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href=#notifiaciones data-toggle="modal" class="link"></a><i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i></li>
        <li><a>{{ user.get_full_name|default:user.username }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="/logout/">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>

{% else %}
        <li><a href=#login data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Log in</a></li>

{% endif %}
```

My problem is when I logout it redirects me to `/logout` and show Django administration page inviting back to login again, while I want a redirection to the main page. How can I achieve this?
Thank you.

Comment: First of all, have you checked if a `LOGOUT_REDIRECTION_URL` cannot be set in `settings.py`?

Comment: @chem1st i don't have set LOGOUT, a question?,`LOGOUT_REDIRECTION_URL` is so how set logout in settings?

Comment: This is a question. I do not know if it should be set like this in `social-auth`, but if its possible it would be the easiest way.

Comment: @chem1st it is not works, i was tried but it yet no works